# Insert no banco de dados gravando pela metade

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, codificação-de-caracteres

Eu pego o nome da notícia e insiro em outra tabela, porém um dos campos esta indo pela metade, segue imagem do *print*:

Banco de dados
[image: imagem do bd]

Código fonte da onde envia:

```
<input name="nomenoticia" type="hidden" id="nomenoticia"
       value="PC realiza apreensão de arma de fogo e droga no Bairro Jardim Esperança." size="80"
       maxlength="100">
```

Trecho do codigo que estou fazendo o insert

```
     $noticia = $_POST['noticia'];
     $titulonoticia = $_POST['nomenoticia'];
     $nome = $_POST['nome'];
     $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
     $status = $_POST['status'];


    $sqlInsert= "INSERT INTO comentarios   (noticia,nomenoticia,nome,comentario,status) VALUES (:noticia,:nomenoticia,:nome,:comentario,:status)";
    $stmt = DB::prepare($sqlInsert);
    $stmt->bindParam("noticia", $noticia);
    $stmt->bindParam("nomenoticia", $titulonoticia);
    $stmt->bindParam("nome", $nome);
    $stmt->bindParam("comentario", $comentario);
    $stmt->bindParam("status", $status);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Não é fácil identificar um problema. Primeiro não sabemos o tamanho máximo da coluna `nomenoticia` que eu acho que é esta que vocês está dizendo que está cortada. Segundo eu não sei se o software que você está usando não está mostrando o resto, se você não deslizou o limite da coluna para mostrar mais partes do texto, ou seja, que seja apenas um problema de visualização e não de programação. Com estas informações, fica mais fácil saber o que acontece.

Comment: a coluna esta vachar(255) quanto ao texto esta sendo mesmo cortado mesmo http://i.imgur.com/lB9WNNP.jpg

Comment: É problema de acentuação. Precisa verificar o *encoding* que está recendo o dado e qual é o *encoding* usado no banco de dados. Por incompatibilidade está descartando tudo à partir do acento.

Comment: Realmente testei aqui em outros campos e aconteceu o mesmo a Colação dos campos estao em utf8_general_ci o banco esta todo em utf-8 e as paginas estao tambem com a met utf-8

Comment: Resolvi o problema, era realmente a meta utf-8 nao tinha na pagina de comentarios. de todo modo obrigado pela atencao

Comment: Vou responder então para não deixar sem resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O corte está acontecendo quando encontra um acento. Então o problema é a incompatibilidade entre a codificação do dados que está sendo enviado pela página e o codificação espera na coluna do banco de dados. Partindo do princípio que a codificação do banco de dados realmente está `utf8_general_ci` e que é difícil se enganar quanto a isto e que não há nada no meio do caminho fazendo conversões, só dá para concluir que que a página específica que está enviando os dados está com codificação diferente da esperada, mesmo que sem querer.

De fato o autor reconheceu que faltava alterar o *encoding* da página para UTF-8.